# Possible Downtime with Azure Devops Deploy to Web APP

Tags: linux, azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to azure community and i bumped into azure devops. I have configured a test pipeline and release. I want to know how Azure Devops takes care of downtimes during deployment in Azure Devops ? If is there is still a downtime, is there anyway to configure an almost zero downtime ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure actually deploy your container with zero downtime
make sure that your container can serve after starting maybe you have some operation at a docker-entrypoint that takes a long time to be done which the container will  be down till finished